# Как вывести выбранные checkbox на той же странице в другом блоке

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте, есть таблица через пхп такого содержания:

```html
$query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `id`, `model`, `name`, `priceor`, `pricecopy` FROM `prices` WHERE `model` = '6'");
                    echo '<table id="rowclick5" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive cursor">
                            <tr style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">
                                <th><center></center></th>
                                <th><center>Наименование</center></th>
                                <th><center>Цена ориг., грн.</center></th>
                                <th><center>Цена копия, грн.</center></th>
                            </tr>';
                    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        echo '<tr>
                                <td><center id="inputcheck"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$result['id'].'" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$result['id'].'"/>'.$result['id'].'</center></td>
                                <td>'.$result['name'].'</td>
                                <td><center>'.$result['priceor'].'</center></td>
                                <td><center>'.$result['pricecopy'].'</center></td>
                            </tr>';
                    }
                    echo '</table>';
```

Как сделать вывод выбранных checkbox на этой же странице только в другом блоке? Сколько пробовал - не получается(

Comment: то-есть? Вам нужно, чтоб при выборе чекбоксов, это отображалось на чекбоксах в другом блоке?

Comment: Мне надо что-бы при выборе checkbox, в другом div на этой же странице выводился id выбранного чекбокса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const gsi=e=>{
  const tmp=document.querySelector("#ids");
  if(!e.checked){//отрицание потому, что на момент зажатия кнопки чекбокс ещё не меняет значение
    e.checked=false;
    const el=document.createElement('div');
    el.id=e.id;
    el.innerHTML=e.id;
    tmp.appendChild(el);
  }else{
    e.checked=true;
    tmp.removeChild(document.querySelector("#ids #"+e.id));
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chebe1" onmousedown="gsi(this)">
<input type="checkbox" id="chebe2" onmousedown="gsi(this)">
<input type="checkbox" id="chebe3" onmousedown="gsi(this)">
<div id="ids">

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Только когда снимаешь чекбокс - запись не убирается, как сделать что-бы убиралась запись, когда снимаешь чекбокс?

Comment: Так убирается же... А что оно, выдаёт ошибку какую-то?

Comment: Вот скриншот: https://imgur.com/a/jDY91

Comment: Т. е. при нажатии на чекбокс - запись появляется, при снятии чекбокса - запись не убирается, при повторном нажатии на чекбокс - появляется еще одна запись.

Comment: Попробуйте теперь

Comment: та же история...

Comment: Если использовать отдельно код который Вы скинули - то работает все отлично, но через таблицу не убирается id

Comment: А скиньте таблтицу с чекбоксами. Ничего не меняя, так как она сейчас есть.

Comment: Она представлена в самом вопросе. Единственное что я добавил к чекбоксам, так это: onmousedown="gsi(this)"